# Knockout.js Jquery Marquee Function

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js, marquee

I'm trying to MARQUEE text using JQUERY.MARQUEE when a condition is met.

For instance, if text.length > 10, Marquee Text.

**CSS:**

```
 <style>
 .title-marquee { 
      color: red !important;
      width: 200px !important;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      display: block !important;
 }
 </style>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <th class="movie-title" data-bind="text: title, css: { 'title-marquee' : title.length > 10 }"></th>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
 $('.title-marquee').marquee({
 duplicated: true
 });
```

I have the HTML & CSS working correctly, but JQUERY isn't initiating.

Comment: Please put up a jsfiddle and I'll do my best to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you `title` must be `title()` HTML will be

```
<th class="movie-title" data-bind="text: title, css: { 'title-marquee' : title().length > 10 }"></th>
```

Here is the working [**JsFiffle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8W9Q/)

Hope. it may help you at some point. Have a nice day :)